# Add sourceforge dependency to Gradle project

Tags: java, maven, gradle, neuroph

I am trying to add [neuroph](https://github.com/neuroph/neuroph) to my Gradle project but am having a bit of trouble. The following is the maven dependency xml that the project provides.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>neuroph.sourceforge.net</id>
        <url>http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
```

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neuroph</groupId>
        <artifactId>neuroph-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.94</version>
    </dependency>
```

My problem is in trying to convert this maven dependency into something that I can add to my Gradle project. Can someone provide me the Gradle dependency that is equivalent to the Maven dependency I provided?

(There is an older version of the project on Maven Central, but the latest version is on SourceForge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to [declare a custom Maven repository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:declaring_custom_repository):

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = "http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/maven2/"
    }
}
```

Then [declare the dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html) as normal:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.neuroph:neuroph-core:2.94"
}
```

I'm guessing at the dependency configuration you want, but `implementation` is the usual one.